# Downloading Census data to PostgreSQL PostGIS TIGER extension for Amazon RDS database

Tags: postgis, united-states, census, tiger, pgadmin-4

Can someone point me toward instructions on how to download census data for the postGIS_tigerP_geocoder extension?

I would like to use the geocode() function, but any query returns 0 results. From reading, I gathered this is because I must first download address and coordinate data from the US census website. Our database is Amazon RDS. My local machine's operating system is Windows 10.

I followed these instructions in the command prompt on my Windows machine ...
https://sparkgeo.com/blog/building-a-us-census-tracts-postgis-database/
When I got up to `mget *`, the ftp connection responded with 

`200 Switching to ASCII mode.
Cannot find list of remote files.`

Comment: Just in case this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), it might help to add *why* you want to do geocoding at the database level rather than leveraging a web service.

Comment: Services like Geocodio are expensive.

Comment: just download the tl_2012_01_tract.zip 16-Aug-2012 21:26 9.6M  https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2012/TRACT/ there are 78 zip files and process the import on your local machine.

Comment: Okay. And if I process the import on my local Windows 10 machine, will this approach save the data to our RDS instance? Or will the geocoding functions only work if run on my local computer/

Comment: you have a postgres database you can copy to another server (local/RDS) using pg_dump https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup-dump.html

Comment: RDS > https://mr-khan.gitlab.io/postgresql/2018/05/14/database-backup-restore-aws-rds-postgresql.html

Comment: Will I need to download all 78 zip files? Like is each one for a different census tract? Or are they all just different versions of the same data?